# Which chapters of HotDQ are important to the overall plot of Tyranny of Dragons?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, hoard-of-the-dragon-queen, rise-of-tiamat

My group just finished the Curse of Strahd campaign a few weeks ago, and now I would like to run Tyranny of Dragons.

My players are level 8, so I thought that would be perfect to start with Rise of Tiamat, but I don't want to skip any important plot points from Horde of the Dragon Queen.

Which chapters, if any, from Horde of the Dragon Queen would I need to run my party through for them to be ready (in terms of plot) for Rise of Tiamat?

Comment: Related: [Seeking player-oriented summary of Hoard of the Dragon Queen](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/185701/seeking-player-oriented-summary-of-hoard-of-the-dragon-queen)

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to play any parts of *Hoard of the Dragon Queen* to prepare your players for *Rise of Tiamat*. The writers of *Rise of Tiamat* anticipated this scenario and included guidance for kicking off the adventure whether you've played *Hoard of the Dragon Queen* before or not.

Minor spoiler below:

> While they might be missing some context for the adventure, the first session involves a council meeting where they can be filled in on all the information they might need.

The only things you will need are:

- A powerful NPC who has reason to think the player characters are trustworthy and capable adventurers.
- Some way of getting the party to Waterdeep if they aren't there already. (The book includes suggestions for this.)

Major spoiler this time:

> The other effect of not having played through *Hoard of the Dragon Queen* is that the players will miss some of the opportunities to score points with the various factions. You could give them some extra points based on their prior exploits, but there are plenty of points to be had, and it shouldn't really be an issue. Especially since the points don't really affect the actual adventure much at all.